# Scraping (french) verb conjugations and importing them to org-mode (to work with org-drill)

Tags: python, org-mode

so I have a pet project: After seeing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uraPXeLfWcM) talk on how to learn Chinese with Emacs, I have decided to try and use org-mode for learning languages as well - specifically with emacs.

Aside from grammar, I want to use it mainly for learning vocab with org-drill. Adding nouns is easy enough via an org-capture-template as I only need to type in the word and its translation which will force me to type it at least once.

However, the spanish.org example on the [org-drill documentation](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-drill.html) site mentions the possibility to also drill verbs.

However, typing in the conjugations of each verb seems like a very repetitive and gruesome process to me. So I want to (semi-)automate this.

Basically what I want is this:

- when in org-mode, I want to be able to hit `C-c` for opening up org-capture and then the keystrokes for a french verb.
- In the capture buffer, I only want to type in the french word and then have the rest done automaticallly for me.
- i.e. create a subheading for each tense with a table containing the conjugations, looking something like this:

  ** Present Tense

  | je vais | nous allons |

  | tu vas  | vous allez  |

  | il/elle/on va | ils/elles vont |

What I have:

- I have a python script that scrapes the desired tenses for a given word for me from www.verbix.com and stores the result in a dictionary.

So, how do I take the resulting dictionary and import it into my french vocab most efficiently (as in least-key-strokes-efficiently, not running-time-efficiently)?

I looked at org-protocol with the capture sub-protocol (just like the firefox add-on). However, this only takes 3 arguments, so I would have to have my script pre-format the dictionary and then take this pre-formatted string as the 'body' argument in org-protocol, right?

Or can someone think about another way to do this, i.e. via an elisp function? I would be willing to delve into elisp and try and learn it. But to be honest I am at a loss where to start and if this is even possible (I guess it is, because it seems nearly anything is with emacs and elisp).

Appreciate the help!